# Netbook won't boot USB

Tags: usb, ubuntu-netbook, vaio

My netbook only shows a blinking dash when booting from removable device. It's a Sony vaio netbook.

Comment: there is no usb legacy support on my bios. its a pcg r505 vaio , its really an old machine so it doesnt have one. any other solutions? .

Comment: Please don't post comments or information as answers. If you have additional information to add, you can edit the original question to do so. If you have a comment or reply to another person, you can always comments on your own questions regardless of your reputation. It appears as though you have an unregistered accounts and cookies disabled. If you create an account and ask a moderator, you can have the unregistered accounts merged and have access to your question again.

Answer (score 0):

First, you should go in BIOS settings and find the page in which you should set what device is run/boot first.

If still doesn't working, look for something called USB Legacy Support in the BIOS. Enabling that should allow the machine to pretend the USB is a hard drive and boot from it. Ubuntu should take over from there.

Answer (score 0):

Without hardware, it's hard to solve your problem....

The easier option would be an external CD, since it can't boot directly from USB.

If that can't be, maybe remove the hard drive (*I know this is a sucking solution but...*) and install it in another computer than moving it back to your netbook.